What do I need to do to prepare this wall for wainscoting and a railing
We have a crack on our stair wall adjacent to where the banister connects.  We are thinking about adding some wainscoting and an additional rail.  What steps should I take to prepare/repair the wall before proceeding?


I had to read this twice... I thought I read "We have crack in our stair wall...".

Cosmetic. Apply plaster patching compound, smooth the surface, touch up the paint.

The crack you are seeing is the corner bead pulling away from the drywall slightly.
If you are installing wainscoting over the crack, you need to do nothing. it is cosmetic and nothing structural.
You can smooth latex caulk or patching compound over any parts exposed and touch up the paint.
